# Insert checkbox column at the end of gridview

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, checkbox

My GridView contains 20 columns which are added programmatically (DataTable, DataColumn, DataRow and DataSet). Now I need to insert a checkbox column as the last column (21<sup>st</sup> column). How should I add it?

I tried adding with the usual Template Field (from design tab) in .aspx file but that adds a checkbox as the first column and **not** as the last one.

Comment: Do you mean say that columns are auto generated for the grid view?

Comment: No columns are not auto generated

Comment: no.. i have added columns and row using data-table, column & row

Comment: Is AutoGenerateColumns="true" or "false" for the GridView?

Comment: nothing has been mentioned for that..

Comment: @suryakiran: that means its autogenerated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are binding your `GridView` using a `DataTable`, do this before you set the `GridView` `DataSource`.

```
dataTable.Columns.Add("Select", Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));

DemoGrid.DataSource = dataTable;
DemoGrid.DataBind();

foreach (GridViewRow row in DemoGrid.Rows)
{
    //check box is the first control on the last cell.
    CheckBox check = row.Cells[row.Cells.Count - 1].Controls[0] as CheckBox;
    check.Enabled = true;
}
```

On an unrelated side note, please note that your `asp:GridView` is in fact *AutoGenerated*.

Comment: thanks..! but the checkbox that is being added are all disabled and unchecked.. any way to enable and check-uncheck?

Answer (score 0):

Create a TemplateField for the column with the check, and add the checkbox at the bottom as a footertemplate, and turn on showing the footer via GridView.ShowFooter = true;  A footer is a great place to put commonly available controls like this.

The common trick, if the footer is not an option, is to bind an empty row of data to the UI, which will have the checkbox.

HTH.

Comment: I think requirement is adding the last column as checkbox, not footer row

Comment: brian, but we dont have a footer row for each gridviewrow:). the only method is see for this problem is to append another column to the dataset of typr boolean that would guarantee a checkbox.

Comment: Oh I see it now, I was really dense.  I didn't see the column part.